# How to reload WebImage when url is changed (swift)?

Tags: swift, webimage

I'm a beginner and sorry for my (probably stupid question)

I use the SDWebImageSwiftUI framework and WebImage to display images from the URL (from firebase). My picture should change on Player if I change the song. I use @State and @Binding to connect a few views and data changes properly (URL, title, etc are actualized). Some time ago everything worked great, and now I don't know when exactly it crashed.
On appear player, when the image is displayed the first time work well but stays the same when the song changes.

```
public struct Song: Identifiable, Codable, Hashable {
   public var id: String = UUID().uuidString
   var image: String
   var title: String
   var author: String
   var track: String
}

WebImage(url: URL(string: song.image))
```

So, what should I do to WebImage changes properly?

Comment: Are you positive that `song` is changing? If you put `Text(song.title)` right above the `WebImage`, does the text change?

Comment: Yes, I see that the title and author changed and also printed song.image (string URL) is also changed

Comment: I'm not familiar with `SDWebImageSwiftUI`, so there very well could be a much better answer than this, but you could force it to reload when the song changes by doing `WebImage(url: URL(string: song.image)).id(song.id)` -- hopefully someone has a better idea, though.

Comment: <3, I used other state to toggle change, and didn't work but your answer work!!! thank you !!

Comment: I would expect to see a @State variable declared or used in here somewhere? I think the `.id(song.id)`  is working by accident. Perhaps post a minimum working View controller example.